# cannot paint on texture

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

So I've been doing the donut tutorial but for some reasons when I open blender back from where I left off, I can't paint on it now, it was perfectly fine before, does anyone know what's the problem here?[image]

Comment: Did you save the image texture to an imagefile before closing Blender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your brush mask.

[image]

on a mask, Black means 0 and white means 1.
you are telling blender to not paint anything by setting a black mask.